# Apache Python 500 internal server error

Tags: python, apache, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, permission-denied

Thank you in advance for any help on this, I am a bit of a newb and have been looking everywhere to figure what I am doing wrong.

I have the Apache 2.4.6, python 2.7 centos 7.

I have a simple python script

```
/var/www/html/test.py
```

In the script it has

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print 'Hello World!'
```

The permission have been checked (777 just because I can't figure it out):

```
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache apache   192 Aug 27 11:45 test.py
```

running the command

```
/var/www/html/test.py
```

works find and displays Hello World!

The log for apache says

```
[Thu Aug 27 11:38:53.703606 2015] [cgi:error] [pid 10218] [client 86.159.50.246:61086] AH01215: (13)Permission denied: exec of '/var/www/html/test.py' failed
```

The relevant apache configuration is as follows:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
<Directory /var/www/html/>
 Order allow,deny
 Require all granted
 allow from all
 Options +ExecCGI
 AddHandler cgi-script .py
</Directory>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated because I have no idea what else I am doing wrong!

Comment: Do you have SELinux enabled?

Comment: It was enabled. Unfortunately when I disabled it and restarted the server I lost the ability to connect to it since its an Amazon server. So I am now trying to rebuild the entire thing on a home VM....

Comment: Ok I have stood up a brand new server everything fresh with everything the same accept I am using sepearate default cgi-bin directory so /var/www/cgi-bin/test.py and 
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    Options +ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .py
</Directory>
and script alias to match. se linux is disabled and I am getting the same error!!!

Comment: Yep, because since you are writing a CGI script, mod_wsgi has got nothing to do with it. You really should move away from using CGI scripts though. If wanting to seriously write Python web applications, start out by learning Flask and when you understand the basics with the development server, only then consider deploying to Apache with mod_wsgi.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the issue. It was that I installed mod_wsgi with yum and it was precomilid for a different version of python. It works with SE linux inabled. To fisc the issue I ran the following lines of code

```
yum install httpd-devel
git clone https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi.git
cd mod_wsgi
./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python2.7    
make
make install
```

Then it output the path of the module (.so) file. It looked right but just for completeness sake I change the file:
/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-wsgi.conf

from

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

to

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

because that was the output path of the make step and it worked!!

Comment: + yum install python-devel